# Typings for ngCordova seem to be missing

Tags: typescript, ngcordova, tsd, typescript-typings

I'm trying to get ngCordova typings but both tsd and typings fail:

If I execute:

```
tsd install ng-cordova --save
```

It Outputs;

> zero results

If I execute:

```
typings install dt~ng-cordova --save --global
```

It outputs:

> typings ERR! message Unable to find "ng-cordova" ("dt") in the
>   registry. Did you want to try searching another source? Also, if you
>   want contribute these typings, please help us:
>   https://github.com/typings/registry typings ERR! caused by
>   https://api.typings.org/entries/dt/ng-cordova/versions/latest
>   responded with 404, expected it to equal 200

I also tried searching, but no look either

```
tsd query ng-cordova
```

Outputs;

> zero results

```
typings search --name ng-cordova
```

Outputs:

> No results found for search

What happened with ngCordova typings? I know they are there: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/ng-cordova

How can I get the typings for ngCordova?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using below for searching all the typings for individual `ng-cordova` services:

```
typings search ng-cordova
```

This will return the result

> Viewing 17 of 17
>   NAME                         SOURCE HOMEPAGE                                                     DESCRIPTION VERSIONS UPDATED
>   ng-cordova/actionsheet       dt     https://github.com/driftyco/ng-cordova                                   1        2016-03-16T17:18:10.000Z
>   ng-cordova/appavailability   dt     https://github.com/driftyco/ng-cordova                                   1        2016-03-16T17:18:10.000Z
>   ng-cordova/app-version       dt     https://github.com/driftyco/ng-cordova                                   1        2016-03-16T17:18:10.000Z
>   ng-cordova/badge             dt     https://github.com/driftyco/ng-cordova                                   1        2016-03-16T17:18:10.000Z
>   ng-cordova/camera            dt     https://github.com/driftyco/ng-cordova                                   1        2016-03-16T17:18:10.000Z
>   ng-cordova/datepicker        dt     https://github.com/VitaliiBlagodir/cordova-plugin-datepicker
>   ng-cordova/device            dt     https://github.com/driftyco/ng-cordova                                   1        2016-03-16T17:18:10.000Z
>   ng-cordova/devicemotion      dt     https://github.com/driftyco/ng-cordova                                   1        2016-03-16T17:18:10.000Z
>   ng-cordova/deviceorientation dt     https://github.com/driftyco/ng-cordova                                   1        2016-03-16T17:18:10.000Z
>   ng-cordova/dialogs           dt     https://github.com/driftyco/ng-cordova                                   1        2016-03-16T17:18:10.000Z
>   ng-cordova/emailcomposer     dt     https://github.com/driftyco/ng-cordova                                   1        2016-03-16T17:18:10.000Z
>   ng-cordova/file              dt     https://github.com/driftyco/ng-cordova                                   1        2016-03-16T17:18:10.000Z
>   ng-cordova/filetransfer      dt     https://github.com/driftyco/ng-cordova                                   1        2016-03-16T17:18:10.000Z
>   ng-cordova/geolocation       dt     https://github.com/driftyco/ng-cordova                                   1        2016-03-16T17:18:10.000Z
>   ng-cordova/network           dt     https://github.com/driftyco/ng-cordova                                   1        2016-03-16T17:18:10.000Z
>   ng-cordova/toast             dt     https://github.com/driftyco/ng-cordova                                   1        2016-03-16T17:18:10.000Z
>   ng-cordova/tsd               dt     https://github.com/driftyco/ng-cordova                                   1        2015-12-02T00:06:10.000Z

So based on above results you can search a specific typing as:

```
typings search ng-cordova/toast
```

When you have found the typing, you can install it as below:

```
typings install ng-cordova/toast
```

Note: All the above works with typings version `0.8.1`

Comment: Shouldn't it be `typings install dt~ng-cordova/toast --global`?